# How to use case and filter with a group by statement and having an aggregate calculation?

Tags: group-by, apache-spark

I would like to do the following

```
SELECT
  PO.col1,
  PO.col2,
  CASE
       WHEN PO.col3 <> 8 THEN PO.col4
       WHEN PO.col3 = 8 
            THEN CASE
                      WHEN (ROUND(CAST(PO.col4 AS double) - SUM(CAST(PO.col5 AS double)), 2)) > 0 
                            AND SUM(CAST(PO.col5 AS double)) > 0
                            THEN ROUND(CAST(PO.col4 AS double) - SUM(CAST(PO.col5 AS double)), 2)
                      END
       END AS Quantity
FROM
  my_table AS PO
GROUP BY 
  PO.col1, PO.col2
HAVING 
  Quantity > 0
```

I apologize for not being able to provide sample data/columns. I am not allowed to share my work data.

The logic which I have been told to implement is as follows.

For each unique pair combination of `col1`, `col2`, get a constructed attribute called `Quantity`. `Quantity = col4` wherever `col3 = 8`. If `col3 != 8`, then check `SUM(col5) > 0`. If yes then check `col4 - SUM(col5) > 0`. If yes, then keep the record, else skip.

Out of my own observation I checked that `COUNT(DISTINCT col4)` for each unique pair of `col1` and `col2` is 1. I hope that's helpful answering my question.

We are working with Spark SQL so I don't know what tag to use for this in the question.

[SAMPLE DATA](https://www.db-fiddle.com/f/pqUGYfTeaKbEHKPv4mWeWL/0)

Comment: Even if you can not share your current data, you could build a simulated scenario with random data just for the sake of the question.

Comment: Ok I will try to build some sample data. I am not sure if it will come out correctly. Please wait.

Comment: I don't know Spark SQL, but you have several columns in your query that are not in an aggregate nor in the GROUP BY clause.

Comment: You can use a fiddle like https://dbfiddle.uk/, https://rextester.com/ or sqlfiddle.com

Comment: @Lennart Exactly. I understand that. But I don't know how to overcome that. Previously I did a `UNION` for the filter `col3 = 8` and `col3 <> 8`. But I have been told to do without the `UNION`. So I am stumped currently. Btw, SPARK SQL, I am currently writing only SQL, nothing specific to SPARK or any other vendor.

Comment: What happens if you just add them to group by?

Comment: There are many distinct values of `col3` for each combination pair for `col1` and `col2`. I require only the combination/pair and the `Quantity` part.

Comment: Does you DBMS support window functions?

Comment: Basically what you are trying to do is: `select x, y ,sum(z) from T group by x`. Given the rows (1,1,1),(1,2,2) what would the correct answer be?

Comment: You could do: `x, y ,sum(z) over (partition by x) from T` if your DBMS support window functions

Comment: @Lennart I have added sample data. Please have a look.

Comment: @McNets I have added sample data. Please have a look.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

FWIW, I think you will be way better of separating the 2 cases for PO.col3, and combine the results with a UNION (which I assume is what you had before). Meanwhile, I tried to fix your query so that it compiles in your fiddle:

```
SELECT * FROM (
    SELECT
        PO.col1,
        PO.col2,
        CASE WHEN PO.col3 <> 8 THEN PO.col4::float
             WHEN PO.col3 = 8 
             THEN CASE WHEN (CAST(PO.col4 AS float) - SUM(CAST(PO.col5 AS float))) > 0 
                        AND SUM(CAST(PO.col5 AS float)) > 0
                       THEN (CAST(PO.col4 AS float) - SUM(CAST(PO.col5 AS float)))
                       END
             END AS Quantity
    FROM mytable AS PO
    GROUP BY PO.col1, PO.col2, PO.col3, PO.col4 
) AS T
WHERE Quantity > 0
```

I have no idea whether it is correct or not, for that I would need a small sample and an expected result.

Comment: Thank you for your answer. It follows the same way I think about it. No I apologize, we don't have an expected result. Basically I'm given the "logic" by ppl working with DOMDs and I have to write queries. The query using UNION and the one you have written apparently are wrong according to those people. I can't help it further. I'll take it up with my superior to ask for the business logic. Thank you again.

Comment: Please have a look at this question here - https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54351525/how-can-i-filter-group-and-do-aggregation-when-it-does-does-not-have-a-specific I have shown exactly how the output should be, which I clarified from the person who gave me the logic. I am still a novice so I find it hard to grasp this logic.